# WPFtoolkit and its DatagridColumnHeader

Tags: datagrid, header, wpftoolkit

I need to have different context menus in my datagrid - one for its header and one for rows of a grid. So I'm handling MouseClick event and than I need to evaluate if the underlying object for mouse cursor is Datagrid's header. Can you explain me how can I make this?
The thing that I can't understand is that neither of DataGrid's and DataGridColumn's hierarchy of objects contain DataGridColumnHeader object or any reference to it. But in virtual tree if I get textblock that is located in header and contains column header's text and then get it parent container, I'll get DatagridColumnHeader object.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
    Dim dep As DependencyObject = DirectCast(e.OriginalSource, DependencyObject)

    ' iteratively traverse the visual tree 
    While (dep IsNot Nothing) AndAlso Not (TypeOf dep Is DataGridRow OrElse TypeOf dep Is Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader OrElse TypeOf dep Is DataGrid)
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep)
    End While

    If dep Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If TypeOf dep Is Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader Then
        Dim CurrentHeader As Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader = TryCast(dep, Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader)
        If Not CurrentHeader Is Nothing Then
            CurrentHeader.ContextMenu.Items.Add("Option")
        End If
    ElseIf TypeOf dep Is DataGridRow Then
        'Something else
    End If
End Sub
```